# My Bot should identify the logged in User name

Tags: azure, chatbot

My Bot should identify the logged-in user name and should display the user name.

Logic have written in MessagesController.cs file and pasted the code in below responses.. Unfortunately I am not getting the logged in user name by using VS 2017. Thanks for your support.
[refer the screen shot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cmxv4.png)

Comment: so what is your problem?

Comment: Unable to retrieve the logged in user name by using the above code

Comment: you should post the code as it is, not the screenshot. so that people can easily help you. also you should write in detail what is the error, what have you tried, which version you are using, what is not working etc. welcome to stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.ConnectorEx;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace Microsoft.Bot.Sample.QnABot
{
[BotAuthentication]
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
/// <summary>
/// POST: api/Messages
/// receive a message from a user and send replies
/// </summary>
/// <param name="activity"></param>
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
public virtual async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] Activity activity)
{
// check if activity is of type message
if (activity.GetActivityType() == ActivityTypes.Message)
{
await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new RootDialog());
}
else
{
HandleSystemMessage(activity);
}
return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
}
private Activity HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
{
if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData)
{
// Implement user deletion here
// If we handle user deletion, return a real message
}
else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
{
// Handle conversation state changes, like members being added and removed
// Use Activity.MembersAdded and Activity.MembersRemoved and Activity.Action for info
// Not available in all channels
//var domain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
//var currentUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domain, User.Identity.Name);
//Activity reply1 = message.CreateReply("Hi  " + currentUser + "");
if (message.MembersAdded.Any(o => o.Id == message.Recipient.Id))
{
StringBuilder stringb = new StringBuilder();
//string loggedUserName = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity.Name;//WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();//System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();//Environment.UserName.ToUpper();
//string loggedUserName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
string fullName = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.GivenName;
string loggedUserName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString(); //WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();////Environment.UserName.ToUpper();
string domainUser = Regex.Replace(loggedUserName, ".*\\\\(.*)", "$1", RegexOptions.None);
//string[] words = loggedUserName.Split("\");
stringb.Append("Hi ");
stringb.AppendLine();
stringb.Append("<b>");
stringb.Append("+ fullName ! +");
stringb.Append("</b>");
stringb.AppendLine();
string finalstring = stringb.ToString();
ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(message.ServiceUrl));
Activity reply1 = message.CreateReply("Hi  " + fullName + "");
Activity reply2 = message.CreateReply("This is HR Bot, an I'm your Virtual assistant. How can I help you with your learning today? ");
connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply1);
connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply2);
}
}
else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate)
{
// Handle add/remove from contact lists
// Activity.From + Activity.Action represent what happened
}
else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Typing)
{
// Handle knowing tha the user is typing
}
else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Ping)
{
}
return null;
} 
}
}
```